# IOS "Add to Home Screen" points to assets folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, safari, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

If I want to add my PWA site to the Home Screen by pressing "Add to Home Screen", Safari points to the assets folder and breaks the routing(navigation) in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that Safari points to the assets/manifest.json file, if its not in the root (same level as the index.html). If it is in the root, navigation works perfectly.
So the lesson is: **put the manifest.json at the same level as the index.html**